import from & from on python with different levels of modules
I see a code like this:
import torch
from torch import nn
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

i'm learning python but i dont see really a doc where can explain the first import, i think two first lines it's equivalent to this in another languages:
from torch import torch.nn

i mean why two lines,  I think because the code use later only torch,
i dont understand the submodles in two levels in python, any url for doc ? what about more than 3 or 4 modules levels ?

Some packages in python contain submodules, that are not loaded by default. This has several advantages. If you don't use the submodule (nn in your case) you don't need to import it, reducing loading time. It is also helps in maintaining a clean and modular codebase and namespace.
With your two imports you essentially import torch and nn, and specify that the package nn can be found within torch as torch.nn.
You can use three keywords when importing: import, from and as, where as is only used to change the package name in local namespace.
A simple import ... [as ...] will just import the package and make it available under the default name or the name specified using as.
When using from ... import ... [as ...] you will import a submodule from a package.
This can also be used to rename a package without as:
from torch import nn is the same as import torch.nn as nn.
You can also always import multiple modules/submodules after the import keyword:
from torch import nn, cuda
This will import torch.nn and torch.cuda.
Your approach with importing both at the same time (from torch import torch.nn) will not work. This would be equivalent to:
import torch.torch.nn as torch.nn or
from torch.torch import nn.
Instead, you could use this:
import torch, torch.nn as nn
For your concern of having to import every submodule on the third and fourth level:
Most submodules are imported by default implicitly. And it is rare to find submodules, that have to be imported explicitly, not on the second level of the package.
In short: If you want to use torch and nn you have to import both. If you only use torch anyways you don't need to import nn.
